# Docker build fails with "failed to calculate checksum: not found" error during COPY command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my Docker image using `docker-compose up -d --build`. The build process fails with the following error message:

```
ERROR [profiles 6/8] COPY --chown=ubuntu:ubuntu ./compose/dev/web/entrypoints /:
------
 > [profiles 6/8] COPY --chown=ubuntu:ubuntu ./compose/dev/web/entrypoints /:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 3f15a420-c6ba-47ed-8967-08acfe264b2c::u63guqaofpvus5yiwjubm1u1r: "/compose/dev/web/entrypoints": not found
```

It seems that the Docker build process is unable to find the specified path `./compose/dev/web/entrypoints`. However, I have verified that the path exists and contains the necessary files.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

- I'm using Docker Compose to manage my multi-container application.
- The `Dockerfile` is located in the root directory of my project, and the `docker-compose.yml` file is also in the same directory.
- The problematic `COPY` command is part of the Dockerfile for building a specific service (`web`).

I've tried troubleshooting by double-checking the file paths, verifying file permissions, and rebuilding the images without using cache, but the issue persists.

Could someone please provide insights into why this error might be occurring and how I can resolve it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that this file or any of it's parents is not in `.dockerignore` first.

Comment: Aside from the specific file path, this seems like essentially the same problem as [your previous question](/q/78016953); what's different?

Comment: @STerliakov, yes it is not in `.dockerignore`

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, because I still have this problem!

Comment: Then please post your directory `tree` and exact command you're running. In which directory are you running it?

Comment: Actually, I fixed it! It was an error with the path. :)

Thank you so much!